# Resolving 404 Errors for Font and Image Files in Express.js Application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm encountering 404 errors when trying to load font and image files in my Express.js application. I have tried various approaches, including using a  tag in my HTML, but some assets are still not being served correctly. I need assistance in identifying and rectifying the issue.

**Problem:**

I'm building a web application using Express.js, and I have a /public directory where my static assets, including fonts and product images, are stored but there is a prefix which i did not add its being added by default this /product-details/ i dont know where this is coming from this happens only when i use /:id.

When I access the application, some of the assets are loaded without any problems, but others are returning 404 errors in the browser console.

**What I've Checked:**

I've verified that the paths to the font and image files are correctly specified in my HTML and CSS files.

I've confirmed that the font and image files exist in the /public directory with the correct file names and extensions.

I've correctly configured Express to serve static files using the express.static middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Sample Error Messages:

Here are some sample error messages I'm encountering in the browser console:

GET http://localhost:3000/product-details/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
font-awesome.min.css:1     GET http://localhost:3000/product-details/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Additional Information:

I've tried adding a  tag to my HTML to ensure that relative paths are resolved correctly, but the issue persists.

My application is running on http://localhost:3000.

**Question:**

How can I resolve the 404 errors for these assets and ensure that all font and image files are correctly served by Express.js? Is there anything else I should check or configure to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

**Hi @erblin,**

Since long time back I had worked with Express.js and facing the same issue and resolved it in a similar way you posted. so I am not sure if any change since then but still I want to suggest you to try below mentioned approch.

As per Express.js documentation:

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

```js
console.log('__dirname :', __dirname);
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

So, here you need to check and confirm that the above code is executing from the root location where your static assets folder (eg. /assets) is available else you can use relative path. (Please refer relative path example code given at the end of this post).

Folder structure might be:
(Reference https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-express-static-function/)

```
public/
 |- Css
 |- js
 |- fonts
node_modules/
views/
src/
server.js
```

[image]

Also try to use `console.log('__dirname :', __dirname);` to check from where it is serving your asset files.

As per my knowledge, the Express.js server will try to find your static assets path from where server (server.js file executed) is started.

**Relative path example:**

```js
console.log('__dirname :', __dirname);
const path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../')));
```

I hope that will be helpful.

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval

Comment: Love the answer you gave i since deleated my project i got to frustrated but i will try it again and see if this works the answer is detailed and very easy to understand thanks.

Comment: Thank you @erblin-krasniqi